# JSON-RPC vs JSON Patch

Tags: json, json-rpc, json-patch

There are a lot of comparisons like "REST vs smth" (eg [vs Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57852689/5308802), [vs JSON-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15056878/5308802)), but I also see many similarities between [JSON-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) and [JSON Patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Patch) – both of them specify operation/method, values/parameters, and allow to perform batch requests. The only difference I see is that JSON-RPC also describes response format with IDs and errors, so it looks more mature. But maybe they just have different pros&cons, different appropriate use cases?

Comment: One could write multiple pages long answer to this and still only touching on it.  I hope this was still helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON-RPC (2.0)](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) is indeed mostly mentioned as a REST alternative. (A look at the more general discussion, [REST](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/follow-up-to-rest-is-the-new-soap-the-origins-of-rest-21c59d243438/) vs [SOAP](https://phil.tech/2017/rest-confusion-explained/) vs [RPC](https://blog.carlosgaldino.com/a-critique-of-the-remote-procedure-call-paradigm-30-years-later.html) might be due but this is a rabbit hole, seriously. Part of the problem is, people talking about different RESTs and RPCs and [confuse them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830431/web-service-differences-between-rest-and-rpc).) Historically, [RPC systems](https://www.simple-is-better.org/rpc/) often suffered from confounded dependences related to schema requirements, custom serializations, protocol restrictions, and complex RPC/function mappings. JSON-RPC tries to entangle dependencies, it does not want to be everything RPC for everybody but to stay relatively narrow in scope. It supports a small(er) set of commands, and is more opinionated on how to implement it. Nonetheless, it's a complete package, highly flexible, and used for complex APIs that [struggle to map all operations to HTTP verbs](https://joost.vunderink.net/blog/2016/01/03/why-we-chose-json-rpc-over-rest/). Newer capabilities like events, notifications, and batch actions make JSON-RPC very versatile and a good choice for all kinds of projects; the additions are especially useful for action-based microservices.

[JSON-Patch (RFC6902)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), arguably, tries to solve a single common problem of APIs, i.e. partial updates. Instead of `PUT`ting or `POST`ing (potentially heavyweight) changes to a (historically) growing URL space, using query params to carry the semantics, or introducing other complexities, JSON Patch offers an atomic update request that patches your JSON using a series of "add", "remove", "replace", "move" and "copy" operations. [To quote](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/09/05/patch) one of the authors of the JSON Patch RFC, Mark Nottingham (IETF):

> This has a bunch of advantages. Since it’s a generic format, you can
> write server- and client-side code once, and share it among a number
> of applications. You can do QA once, and make sure you get it right.
> Furthermore, your API will become less complex, because it has less
> URI conventions, leading to more flexibility and making it easier to
> approach for new developers. Using this approach will also make caches
> operate more correctly; since modifications to a resource will
> “travel” through its URL, rather than some other one, the right stored
> responses will get invalidated.

Similar things can be said about [JSON Merge Patch (RFC7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396), which can be used for the same purpose but works more like a diff/patch that simply contains the changes instead of using mutating operations. In this respect, JSON Merge Patch is simpler but more limited than JSON Patch, e.g. you cannot set a key to `null` (since null means remove), merging only works with objects `{..}`, arrays `[..]` can only be replaced as a whole, and merging never fails, could cause side-effects and is therefore not transactional. This renders Merge Patch (overly) simplistic and impractical for certain real-world applications. There are more related projects named like JSON-Diffpatch, etc that take similar approaches.

In general, all of them have advantages and disadvantages, and none of them will fit everybody's use-cases. It really depends on [what problems you want to solve with your APIs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/rest-vs-rpc-what-problems-are-you-trying-to-solve-with-your-apis). JSON-RPC is arguably more versatile and mature, however, JSON-Patch is also a sound choice, especially if you control both sides of the communication.

Comment: Amazing answer! Also, do you now, is there some comparison table for more clarification of capabilities, pros/cons of these and possible other approaches? Or, maybe you could create such table to share knowledge and experience in a brief visual way? 